How to detect constructor type mismatch in TypeScript?
This code compiles without errors, although two of the constructors do not match the declared constructor type.
How to detect constructor type mismatch?
type ObjConstructor = new (name: string) => Obj   // type of constructor     (string) => 

// or by interface — doesn't matter
// interface ObjConstructor {
//   new (name: string): Obj
// }

class Obj {
    constructor(private id: number) { }    // first conflicting constructor  (number) => 
    print() { console.log(this.id) }
}

class Sub extends Obj {  
    constructor() { super(0) }             // second conflicting constructor () =>
}

function foo(f: ObjConstructor) {          // function expects signature     (string) =>
    const obj = new f('name')

    if (obj instanceof Sub) {
        obj.print()
    }
}

foo(Sub)  // wrong signature sent here   (number) =>  or () =>

Link to playground

It's not a type mismatch; it's intentional, as per the FAQ. Sub's constructor will happily ignore the extra "name" argument. Why do you want to prohibit this? Can you [edit] to show a situation where an actual problem happens? Also, what "two" constructors? foo(Obj) is an error, so there's no problem there.

jcalz, thanks, I didn't know about this! I am studying Ts without much knowledge about Js.

So what should we do with this question? Should I write an answer that explains why it behaves the way it does, as opposed to trying to force TS to do something it doesn’t want to do?

jcalz, thanks to your links, I now understand why functions are compared so freely.
Therefore, my question can be considered resolved.
I really don’t know how it works here — do I need to click somewhere or delete the question if it is considered closed?
